# Prevent dict from creating in list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary from an xlsx file. Here is the code:

```
import pyexcel as pe

records = pe.get_records(file_name="testxl.xlsx")
```

This is creating the dict but stuffing it inside a list. First, how do I stop it from actually creating the dict inside the list? Second, Why is it doing this? Is it better for some reason? I have read the posts on here about accessing data through the list, I just do not see the point of having it at all.

Comment: Why is it doing that? Because that's what it's *supposed* to do: [*"Obtain a list of records from an excel source"*](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/pyexcel.get_records.html?highlight=get_records#pyexcel-get-records). If you just want the first record, access it by index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the `pyexcel` API documentation, [the `get_records` function](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/pyexcel.get_records.html?highlight=get_records#pyexcel-get-records) loads the excel file line by line, providing a list of dictionaries with column headers as keys and field entries as values. If you happened to work with CSV (comma-separated-value) APIs - they tend to work the same way. It's simply the most straight-forward way to retrieve the tabular data.